# Missing some standard library header files in Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, sdk

I am really rusty when it comes to writing code on Windows. From what I know for 2015 there was a change in the way even the standard library is shipped (UCRT in particular).

So now I am standing in front of a **Visual Studio 2015 project targeting Windows 8.1 SDK with build toolset v140** that doesn't compile due to a library (part of the project) not being able to find `sstream`, `memory`, `excpt`. I even checked `excpt` and the error comes from `Windows.h`.

I also have Visual Studio 2017. I went on using the installer to install Windows SDK. The problem is there are many versions of it...

Currently I have (quoting 1:1 what Visual Studio 2017 installer is giving me):

- VC++ 2015.3 v14.00 (v140) toolset
- VC++ 2017 version 15.9 v14.16 latest v141 tools
- Windows Universal CRT SDK
- Visual C++ ATL for x86 and x64
- Visual C++ MFL for x86 and x64
- Windows 10 SDK (10.0.10240.0)
- Windows 10 SDK (10.0.10586.0)
- Windows 10 SDK (10.0.14393.0)
- Windows 10 SDK (10.0.15063.0) for Desktop C++ [x86 and x64]
- Windows 10 SDK (10.0.15063.0) for UWP: C#, VB, JS
- Windows 10 SDK (10.0.15063.0) for UWP: C++
- Windows 10 SDK (10.0.16299.0) for Desktop C++ [x86 and x64]
- Windows 10 SDK (10.0.16299.0) for UWP: C#, VB, JS
- Windows 10 SDK (10.0.16299.0) for UWP: C++
- Windows 10 SDK (10.0.17134.0)
- Windows 10 SDK (10.0.17763.0)
- Windows 8.1 SDK
- Windows Universal C Runtime

I'm assuming Windows 8.0 SDK is not listed, since it's an essential component that gets shipped with Windows 10 upon installing the OS.

When looking for `memory.h` it appears that it's only in the `ucrt` subdirectory of each Windows 10 SDK (e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt\memory.h`.

I come from Linux where in all honesty things appear to be simpler when it comes to setting up a development environment (I can only imagine what it is to develop cross-platform on Windows -_-) so I am probably missing something rather obvious here.

Can I mix **includes** from different SDKs? (here: Windows 10 and 8.1 SDK) Upgrade is currently not an option. If that's not possible how do I deal with the situation?

Answer (score 1):

You're coming from Linux, where things are mixed up. Windows is actually a lot cleaner.

1. The Windows OS headers come from the SDK.
2. The language headers come from the language implementation

C++ has headers such as `<memory>` (note the lack of `.h`). These will come from Visual Studio. This is not the same header as `memory.h`. Similarly, `<sstream>` is another C++ and therefore Visual Studio header.

The UCRT is a bit of a special case - it's a Universal C RunTime. C as a language is stable (which is a nice way to say there's not much improvement anymore). Windows ships a fairly decent chunk of the C standard library in the UCRT. Since C++ includes the C Standard Library in its own, Visual Studio can build on top of the UCRT.

Another major difference is that the Windows SDK's are SDK's for a particular Windows version **and many preceding versions**. There's no need to use the Windows 8.1 SDK; everything in there is also in all the Windows 10 SDK's. Also, the Windows SDK's are not tied to Windows itself. You can develop for Windows 10 using the Windows 10 SDK on Windows 8. There would never be a reason to mix two SDK's.